# How can I make my discord.py bot upload a file to dropbox and then send me a link?

Tags: discord, discord.py, dropbox, dropbox-api

So I recently made a bot that can move files around where needed on my pc, however I would like some things in the cloud with direct access
I also want to be able to share the links to the files to a central place (Discord) so I can access them anywhere.
I'm now wondering is there a way to make my bot upload files to dropbox (or any other file hoster) and then have the links to the files placed into a discord server for me to access?
any help on this would be greatly appreciated

As I cant send files larger than 8mb to a discord server, I run my code

```
dir_path = "C:/Users/me/Documents/py/bot/files"
res = []
for path in os.listdir(dir_path):
    if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(dir_path, path)):
        res.append(path)
for r in res:
    with open(dir_path + "\\" + r, 'rb') as f:
        File = discord.File(f)
        await ctx.channel.send(file=File)
```

And nothing happens at all becuase of the 8mb file limit where I have some files that are 50mb+

Comment: Based on your demand, why send the corresponding file (which can easily go over 8mb limit) to discord? You can use dropbox API python SDK (google it) and share the URL  of uploaded file on dropbox to discord (which is a string less than 2k characters definitely)?

Answer (score 0):

Dropbox does offer an API you can use for listing, uploading, downloading, and sharing files, among other operations. You can find everything you need to get started with the Dropbox API, including documentation, tutorials, and SDKs here:

- https://www.dropbox.com/developers

The following guides may be helpful:

- https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/getting-started
- https://developers.dropbox.com/dbx-file-access-guide

For example, there's an official Dropbox Python SDK here:

- https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-python

To upload files up to 150 MB size with that, you would use `files_upload`:

- https://dropbox-sdk-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/dropbox.html#dropbox.dropbox_client.Dropbox.files_upload

For larger files, you would use "upload sessions":

- https://dropbox-sdk-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/dropbox.html#dropbox.dropbox_client.Dropbox.files_upload_session_start

And to create a shared link for a file, you would use `sharing_create_shared_link_with_settings`:

- https://dropbox-sdk-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/dropbox.html#dropbox.dropbox_client.Dropbox.sharing_create_shared_link_with_settings